# how to link to another page after inserting data in prompt box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a prompt box, after inserting phone number to my I want to redirect to another page, how would I achieve that

```js
         function myFunction() {
          var txt;
          var number = prompt("Please enter your phone number:");
          if (numer !== null ) {
            window.location.href = '{url "loststuffapp:claim"}'; 
          } else {
            txt = "You must enter your phone number";
          }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Taarifa zaidi</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
 window.location.href = "yourfile.html";
```

**Note**:you not used your variable in `if` statement. So it will throw new undefined variable error.

```
var number = prompt("Please enter your phone number:");
    if (numer !== null ) {
```

**See**:`number` and `numer`

```js
function myFunction() {
      var txt;
      var number = prompt("Please enter your phone number:");
      if (number) {
        window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com'; 
      } else {
        txt = "You must enter your phone number";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `yourfile.html` means that you should put your filename that place

Comment: @Kelvin check my answer. I have eddited it in w3c and its working

Comment: @Kelvin waiting to see your comment

Comment: Thanks it works now, I have came to realize pop up message was blocked

Answer (score 5):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter your number</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var number = prompt("Enter your number");
  if (number != "") {
   var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
var URL = "https://www.google.com";
var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update 01**

Adding `number != ""` to `if` statement.

Comment: But when I not enter number, this executes that time also

Comment: Yes the problem is that you are checking the `number` variable which is assiged to  `Enter your numer` which is not null.

Comment: So we should use`if(number)`

Comment: @Rk003 check it now and if you feel this is the answer please mark it as an answer and your upvote is valuable

Comment: @Rk003 yes we can use many methods like `isNaN` and like you said too

Comment: I have not asked this question so I couldn't mark it as answer, anyway this code now working fine.

Comment: @Rk003 ohhh sorry i think i missed the relevant guy. sorry

Comment: Thanks it works now, I have came to realize pop up message was blocked

Comment: The thing is, I can't mark two answers, they have have restricted to only one answer